# How do I populate a Mutable map using a loop in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hashmap

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

var overlapByY: Map[Int, Int] = (0 to records.length).map(a => (a, 0)).toMap
```

Gives the error

```
polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : Map          (in scala.collection.immutable)
[error]  required: Map[Int,Int] (in scala.collection.mutable)
[error]             var overlapByY: Map[Int, Int] = (0 to 8).map(a => (a, 0)).toMap
[error]                                                                       ^
```

Comment: While all the answers below are correct, the best advice you can get here is _do not use mutable collections_. Also, do not use `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toMap` explicitly results in an immutable `Map` (even though the implementation probably uses a mutable `Map` internally...)

There are a few ways to go about this.  I would tend to use `foldLeft`:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

(0 to records.length)  // note that to is inclusive, 0 until records.length might actually be what you want...
  .foldLeft(mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]) { (map, elem) =>
    map += elem -> 0
  }
```

This would be equivalent to the even more imperative:

```scala
{
  val map = mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]
  (0 to records.length).foreach { elem => map += elem -> 0 }
  map
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`toMap` returns an `immutable.Map` so you can't use that if you want a `mutable.Map`. Use the `to` method with the `mutable.Map` object as parameter:

```
  val overlapByY: mutable.Map[Int, Int] =
    (0 to records.length).map(a => (a, 0)) to mutable.Map
```

Since it's mutable, you can make `overlapByY` a `val`, and still add elements to it:

```
  overlapByY += ( 1 -> 2)
```

For older versions of Scala, the old way of doing this was by passing the result of the `map` as a repeated-parameter using `_*` to the `apply` method of the `mutable.Map`:

```
  val overlapByY2 =
    mutable.Map((0 to records.length).map(a => (a, 0)): _*)
```

Comment: Hmm, I get the error:
```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.Map.type
[error]  required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,(Int, Int),?]
[error]             var overlapByY: mutable.Map[Int, Int] = (0 to records.length).map(a => (a, 0)) to mutable.Map
```

Comment: What version of Scala are you using ? This runs fine on Scala 2.13.8.  You only need to import the `mutable` package: `import scala.collection.mutable` for this, not  the whole `mutable.Map`.

Comment: scalaVersion := "2.12.15", Ah right makes sense. Thanks for your help though! Will implement this solution once I update my ver